# How to make speedramp using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to speedup video smoothly than slow down to original state

Demo: https://youtu.be/jaFdS3HAwwA

```
 ./ffmpeg -i 11.mov   
    -filter_complex      "
    [0:v]trim=0:5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];       
    [0:v]trim=5:7.5,setpts=(1-T*0.05)*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];   
    [0:v]trim=7.5:10,setpts=(What Should i write here %))*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v3];       
    [0:v]trim=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4];       
    [v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=4:v=1"   -preset superfast -profile:v baseline output.mp4
```

I'm trying to speed up from 5-7.5 and slow down from 7.5-10 than play rest with 1x of speed

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using adobe after effects extendscript now and life became much easier))